# Calculating the inverse Fourier transform of $\cosh(t\sqrt{1-k^2})$.

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, contour-integration

So i am trying to calculate the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}\cosh(t\sqrt{1-k^2})dk
\end{equation}
I think this should be related to modified Bessel function of first kind, so somehow i am trying to relate it to the integral form of modified Bessel function of first kind with no luck, which is
\begin{equation}
I_n(x)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{x\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)d\theta
\end{equation}
I would appreciate some ideas

Comment: Just a comment but you may be aware that your function is not in $L^1$ (or $L^2$) so your integral should be intended in the sense of distribution. For large $k$ the function approx $\cos(tk)$ so there seems to be a delta lurking somewhere.

Comment: There will be a Heaviside step function of the form $\Theta(t-|x|)$, in the solution of that integral, due to finite velocity of the particle so that might be the reason for that delta function

Comment: Also I believe

$$\cosh\left(t\, \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)\approx (\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(k t)+\cos(k t)$$

and using your definition of the inverse Fourier transform one has

$$\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[(\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(k t)+\cos(k t)](x)=\\\pi \delta(x-t)+\pi \delta(t+x)+\frac{\pi\, (\cosh(t)-1)}{2 t} (\text{sgn}(t-x)+\text{sgn}(t+x))$$ which is the sum of two delta functions and a rectangle function which seems to be consistent with both of the comments above.

Comment: @StevenClark Just curious ... What is the basis for that approximation?  Is that a "large $k$" approximation?

Comment: @MarkViola It was an attempt to approximate $\cosh\left(t\, \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)$ more closely near the origin, but the accuracy of the approximation does increase as $k$ increases. This [WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BCosh%5B1Sqrt%5B1-k%5E2%5D%5D%2C+%28Cosh%5B1%5D-1%29+Sinc%5B1+k%5D%2BCos%5B1+k%5D%2C+Cosh%5B1+Sqrt%5B1-k%5E2%5D%5D-%28%28Cosh%5B1%5D-1%29+Sinc%5B1+k%5D%2BCos%5B1+k%5D%29%7D%2C+%7Bk%2C+-20%2C+20%7D%5D) illustrates the approximation for $t=1$.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer as it doesn't provide a closed-form result, but nevertheless I believe it provides some useful insight.

---

Assuming $t\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the approximation

$$\cosh\left(t\, \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)\approx (\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(t k)+\cos(t k)\tag{1}$$

which increases in fidelity as $|k|$ increases since

$$\underset{k\to\pm\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\cosh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)-\cos(t k)\right)=\underset{k\to\pm\infty}{\text{lim}}(\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(t k)=0\tag{2}$$

and also increases in fidelity as $|t|$ decreases since

$$\underset{t\to 0^-}{\text{lim}}\left(\cosh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)-((\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(t k)+\cos(t k))\right)=\underset{t\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\cosh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)-((\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(t k)+\cos(t k))\right)=0\tag{3}.$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates $u(k)=\cosh\left(t\, \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)$ in blue overlaid by $v(k)=(\cosh(t)-1)\, \text{sinc}(t k)+\cos(t k)$ in orange and their difference $u(k)-v(k)$ in green for the case $t=1$ where $u(k)$ and $v(k)$ correspond to the left and right sides of the approximation in formula (1) above.

---

[image: Illustration of u(k), v(k), and u(k)-v(k) in blue, orange, and green]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $u(k)$, $v(k)$, and $u(k)-v(k)$ in blue, orange, and green

---

The inverse Fourier transform of $\cos(t k)$ is

$$\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[\cos(t k)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(t k)\, e^{-i x k} \, dk=\pi\, \delta(x-t)+\pi\, \delta(x+t)\tag{4}$$

which converges in a distributional sense.

---

The remainder of this answer assumes the case $t=1$ and focuses on comparing the inverse Fourier transforms of

$$G(k)=(\cosh(1)-1)\, \text{sinc}(k)\tag{5}$$

and

$$H(k)=\cosh\left(\sqrt{1-k^2}\right)-\cos(k)\tag{6}$$

related to the approximation

$$H(k)\approx G(k)\tag{7}$$

(which is based on the approximation in formula (1) above) where the inverse Fourier transform of $G(k)$ has the closed form representation

$$g(x)=\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[G(k)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(k)\, e^{-i k x} \, dk\\=\frac{\pi\, (\cosh(1)-1)}{2} (\text{sgn}(x+1)+\text{sgn}(1-x))\tag{8}$$

corresponding to a scaled rectangle function of width $2$ centered about the origin.

---

Now consider the "nested" Fourier series representation

$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{\omega}[F(\omega)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)\, e^{2 \pi i x \omega} \, d\omega=\underset{N, f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\sum _{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right)\, F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 n-1}\right)\\-\frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{4 n-2}\right)\right)\right),\quad F(-\omega)=F(\omega)\tag{9}$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and the parameter $f$ in the upper evaluation limits of the two inner sums over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

---

[My related MSO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462653) provides information on the derivation of formula (9) above (which corresponds to formula (11) in my related MSO question).

---

I believe the inverse Fourier transforms of $G(k)$ and $H(k)$ defined in formulas (5) and (6) above can both be recovered from formula (9) above as follows

$$g(x)=\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[(G(k)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(k)\, e^{-i k x} \, dk=f\left(-\frac{x}{2 \pi}\right),\quad F(\omega)=G(\omega)\tag{10}$$

$$h(x)=\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[(H(k)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(k)\, e^{-i k x} \, dk=f\left(-\frac{x}{2 \pi}\right),\quad F(\omega)=H(\omega)\tag{11}$$

where $f\left(-\frac{x}{2 \pi}\right)$ in formulas (10) and (11) above accounts for the different definitions of the inverse Fourier transform assumed by formula (9) above and this question, and $F(\omega)$ referenced in formulas (10) and (11) above refer to $F(\omega)$ referenced in formula (9) above.

---

Figures (2) and (3) below illustrate formula (8) for $g(x)$ above in blue overlaid by $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ recovered from formulas (10) and (11) above in orange and green respectively where $f(x)$ in formula (9) above is evaluated at $f=25$ and $N=20$ in Figure (2) below and at $f=50$ and $N=10$ in Figure (3) below. Note formula (10) for $g(x)$ (orange) seems to be converging to formula (8) for $g(x)$ (blue), whereas formula (11) for $h(x)$ (green) seems to be converging to sort of a scaled rectangle function of approximately the same width and height but with a concave top.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (8) for g(x) in blue and formulas (10) and (11) for g(x) and h(x) in orange and green]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (8) for $g(x)$ in blue and formulas (10) and (11) for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in orange and green

---

[image: Illustration of formula (8) for g(x) in blue and formulas (10) and (11) for g(x) and h(x) in orange and green]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (8) for $g(x)$ in blue and formulas (10) and (11) for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in orange and green

---

Figure (4) below illustrates $g_8(x)$ in blue overlaid by $h(x)=g_8(x)+\left(h_{11}(x)-g_{10}(x)\right)$ in green where the subscripts refer to the formula numbers above and where $f(x)$ in formula (9) above is evaluated at $f=50$ and $N=10$. The idea behind this evaluation is to attempt to recover a more accurate representation of $h(x)$ by smoothing out the oscillations in the evaluation of formula (11) for $h(x)$ by subtracting the corresponding oscillations in the evaluation of formula (10) for $g(x)$. I suspect the fidelity of this evaluation degrades as $x$ approaches $\pm 1$ from the origin due to the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) since in Figure (2) above the magnitude of the initial overshoot seems to be higher for the evaluation of formula (10) for $g(x)$ (orange) than for formula (11) for $h(x)$ (green). This difference in overshoots seems to suggest to me that $h(x)$ is smoother in some sense than $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $\pm 1$ from the origin which is kind of opposite of what is depicted in Figure (4) below.

[image: Illustration of g_8(x) in blue overlaid by h(x)=g_8(x)+(h_{11}(x)-g_{10}(x)) in orange]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of $g_8(x)$ in blue overlaid by $h(x)=g_8(x)+\left(h_{11}(x)-g_{10}(x)\right)$ in green

---

The remainder of this answer explores another relationship based on the first comment below.

---

Assuming the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is defined as

$$F(k)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](k)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, e^{i k x} \, dx\tag{12}$$

and inverse Fourier transform 0f $F(k)$ is defined as

$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[F(k)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(k)\, e^{-i x k} \, dk\tag{13},$$

then for

$$F(k)=\cosh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\, \sinh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)\tag{14}$$

it appears the conjectured inverse Fourier transform of $F(k)$ would actually be

$$f(x)=\pi\, \delta (x-t)+\pi\, \delta (x+t))\\+\pi \left(I_0\left(\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\right)+\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\, I_1\left(\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\right)\right)\, \theta(t-|x|)\tag{15}$$

which seems to be a pretty good approximation if not an exact relationship.

---

Noting the Fourier transform

$$\mathcal{F}_x[\pi\, \delta (x-t)+\pi\, \delta (x+t)](k)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\pi\, \delta (x-t)+\pi\, \delta (x+t))\, e^{i k x} \, dx=\cos(t k)\tag{16}$$

consider the function

$$J(k)=\cosh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\,\sinh\left(t \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)-\cos(t k)\tag{17}$$

and the conjectured Fourier transform

$$J(k)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-t}^t \pi \left(I_0\left(\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\right)+\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\, I_1\left(\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\right)\right) e^{i k x} \, dx\tag{18}$$

for recovering the function $J(k)$.

---

Figure (5) below illustrates formula (17) for $J(k)$ above minus formula (18) for $J(k)$ above for the case $t=1$ where numeric integration is used to evaluate the conjectured Fourier transform integral in formula (18) above. Note the difference is on the order of $10^{-15}$ which seems to suggest the conjectured Fourier transforms in formula (18) above and the conjectured inverse Fourier transfor in formula (15) above are both correct.

[image: Illustration of formula (17) for J(k) minus formula (18) for J(k) for the case $=1]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of formula (17) for $J(k)$ minus formula (18) for $J(k)$ for the case $t=1$

Comment: I most likely know the correct result as it is related to a result from a paper i was reading, it isn't in closed form , from that paper what i concluded is that inverse Fourier transform of $cosh(t\sqrt{1-k^2})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}sinh(t\sqrt{1-k^2})$most likely be : \begin{equation} \delta(x-t)+\delta(x+t) +\left(I_0(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})+\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}I_1(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})\right)\Theta(t-|x|)   \end{equation} here $I_0$ and $I_1$ are modified Bessel function of first kind. But I am unable to prove this