Fourier transform of $\cosh(\sqrt{a^2-x^2})-\cos(x)$
I would like to show that the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\cosh(\sqrt{a^2-x^2})-\cos(x)$, with the convention
$$
\hat f(k) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{2\pi}e^{-ikx} f(x),
$$
is given by
$$
\hat{f}(k) = \frac{a \,I_1\left(a\sqrt{1-k^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{1-k^2}}
$$
for $k\in ]-1,1[$. Here $I_\nu(z)$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind.
I have checked that it works numerically, as well as when expanding both sides in $a$, but I am looking for a demonstration of this fact.

EDIT
I think I've found a way, though I haven't managed to fill in all the details. Here's the idea if someone sees how to figure this out.
By a simple change of variables, we can rephrase the problem as showing that
$$
F_1(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{2\pi}e^{-ikx} \left(\cosh(a\sqrt{1-x^2})-\cos(ax)\right)=\frac{a \,I_1\left(\sqrt{a^2-k^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{a^2-k^2}}.
$$
Performing first a Laplace transform, and computing the Fourier transform, one gets
$$
\tilde F_1(s) = \frac{s}{2\sqrt{s^2-1}}e^{-\sqrt{s^2-1}|k|}-\frac{e^{-s|k|}}2,
$$
where the second term comes from $\cos(a x)$, and $s>1$ at least for the first term. The latter has a branch-cut for $s\in[-1,1]$.
Here is where things become muddy and help is welcome. I think the second term is here to make everything well-behaved for large $s$. Assuming that thanks to that, we can deform the contour to loop around the branch-cut, one can convince oneself (I have some signs floating around) that we can get to
$$
F_2(a)=\mathcal L^{-1}(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s^2-1}}e^{-\sqrt{s^2-1}|k|})(a) = \frac12\int_0^\pi \frac{dt}{2\pi} e^{i k \sin(t)+a\cos(t) }=I_0(\sqrt{a^2-k^2})/2,
$$
and finally
$$F_1(a) = \partial_a F_2 = \frac{a \,I_1\left(a\sqrt{a^2-k^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{a^2-k^2}}.$$

I believe you meant $k\in [-1,1]$ corresponding to $\hat{f}(k)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{a, I_1\left(a, \sqrt{1-k^2}\right)}{2, \sqrt{1-k^2}} & | k| \leq 1 \
0 & \text{otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.$.

A curious similar result starting from a very different integral here

@StevenClark In the problem I'm considering, $k^2$ is less that $1$, so I've not looked into $k>1$. The substraction of the $\cos$ is to prevent Diract-delta's at $k=±pm1$. MSE just suggested this question you answered to : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4868103/calculating-the-inverse-fourier-transform-of-cosht-sqrt1-k2?rq=1
It is indeed the same problem. In my case, I know what the result is (it comes from two very different way to solve a stat-physics problem), but I would like to prove it...

@StevenClark I think I've found the way to go, but there's some details I still cannot finish to complete, see edit. Maybe you have a clue on how to proceed!
